How to find out the FPS in a video using Nvidia DALI?
I need to know the time of each frame in the video, for this I want to use FPS, but, unfortunately, I could not find any information in the documentation on how to get FPS from the read video.
@pipeline_def
def video_read_pipe():
    video = fn.readers.video(
        filenames=[vid_name],
        name="video reader",
        sequence_length=num_frames,
        file_list_include_preceding_frame=True,
        device="gpu",
        seed=42,
        #stride=10,
        read_ahead=False,
        random_shuffle=False,
        skip_vfr_check=True
    )
    return video


batch_size = 1
pipe = video_read_pipe(batch_size=batch_size, device_id=1, num_threads=4)
pipe.build()

dali_iter = DALIGenericIterator([pipe], ["data"], reader_name="video reader")

I tried with
pipe.reader_meta()
But there was no FPS info

Note: "NVIDIA Data Loading Library (DALI) is a portable, open-source software library for decoding and augmenting images, videos, and speech to accelerate [...]"

frame rate is an illusion. frames have a presentation timestamp. from that you could estimate a frame rate, but if those frames aren't equally spaced in time, you'll have to make decisions. this "DALI" thing might not give you that. you might have to find another library.
